# Can't find the first row where the cell is greater than a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have data in column A, with a header "Time" in cell A1. I am trying to locate the address of the first cell in column A where the cell value is greater than 1. This should be in cell A12.

[image: Sample Data]

However, when using the following code, I get the cell address of $A$1.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A>1,0),)))
```

Comment: Easiest fix is to change the reference A:A to not include A1:  A2:A13 for example.

Comment: or change the match to `MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A>1)*(ISNUMBER(A:A)),0),),0)`

Comment: And please tell us that this is the final output, that you are not going to then use that address in another formula.  If you are there are better ways.

Comment: @ScottCraner I used your change to MATCH to get the cell address that I needed, but you are right, I am planning to use the address later. My current plan is to set a variable to that address so I can use it to specify a range. I have data that goes for hours, but I only want to use data less than an hour in my analysis.

Comment: you are going to use that in vba?

Answer (score 0):

gets the address of the first value that is 1 or greater than 1 in column A

="$A$" & COUNTIF(A:A,"<"&1)+1

Comment: This only works if the values are sorted in order, otherwise it will return the wrong address.